# error starting a shiny web app in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

I have the latest version of Rstudio (0.99.902), and tried to start new shiny web app (the 'create new shiny web app' command button under 'add script' tab on Rstudio desktop IDE). But I got a weird error message - (TypeError) : undefined is not an object (evaluating 'c.b'). Same thing happened to clicking on 'run documents' command button when I tried to build a shiny-embedded markdown file (though I don't have problem building the file by running command - rmarkdown::run('example.rmd')).

Comment: how do your `server.R` and `ui.R` files look like?

Comment: I cannot get to the pop-up window that ask for app name, app file type or directory. Right after I click on 'create a new shiny web application', I got error message. But I am able to run commands to build the app in R console. I think this must be issues with Rstudio, sort of incompatibility. forgot to mention my R version is 3.1.1.

Comment: The error message sounds a lot like a JavaScript error. Most JavaScript libraries Shiny uses are written in a "minimal" fashion, where all variable names are just "a", "b", "c", ... So I guess it's not RStudio, but the App. Can you post your files, please?

Comment: I don't even build any files yet. I just clicked on 'create a new shiny web application' command button(I think this is a new feature of Rstudio Version 0.99.902 IDE, then this error message pops up. As well as 'run documents' command button on markdown script IDE.